# Prolog Comparison Returns False

Tags: prolog, comparison, equality

I apologise upfront as I suspect this is a basic prolog question.
I have the following knowledge base to define a family tree

```
male(james1).
male(james2).
male(charles1).
male(charles2).
male(george1).

female(catherine).
female(elizabeth).
female(sophia).

parent(charles1, james1).
parent(elizabeth, james1).
parent(charles2, charles1).
parent(catherine, charles1).
parent(james2, charles1).
parent(sophia, elizabeth).
parent(george1, sophia).
```

I wrote the following query

```
parent(charles1,james1) == parent(elizabeth,james1).
```

I expected *true* as james1 is the parent of elizabeth and charles1.
Both queries return *true* so why does the `==` return *false*?

Answer (score 3):

Prolog does not have functions which return values. The `male`, `female` and `parent` terms in your knowledge base represent predicates.

Predicate either succeed or fail, they do not return boolean values. If you want to query if two terms `A` and `B` succeed, you can do `A, B` which succeeds only when both of them succeeds (under shared variable instantiation).

So do:

```
| ?- parent(charles1,james1), parent(elizabeth,james1).

yes

| ?- parent(charles1, X), parent(elizabeth, X).

X = james1

yes
```

For disjunction you can use `A; B`.

What you actually did with `==` is compare if the two terms are equal.

> @Term1 == @Term2
> True if Term1 is equivalent to Term2. A variable is only identical to a sharing variable.

```
| ?- parent(charles1,james1) == parent(elizabeth,james1).
no

| ?- parent(charles1,james1) == parent(charles1,james1).
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
parent(charles1,james1) == parent(elizabeth,james1).
```

returns `false`, because it just compares two prolog *terms* for identity. No lookup is done against your `parent/2` facts in the prolog database.

Prolog is a *declarative language*, not a procedural language. You define what constitutes truth in terms of predicate calculus... and then let Prolog's inference engine evaluate it.

It sound like you want to query if two people are siblings (e.g., have a common parent). You could say something like

```
siblings(A,B)  :- % A and B are siblings, IFF...
  parent(A,P) ,   % A has parent P, and
  parent(B,P) ,   % B likewise has parent P
  .
```

That `siblings/2` predicate defines a search tree.

What happens [conceptually] when you then query

```
siblings(A,B).
```

is that Prolog's inference engine does a depth-first, left-to-right traversal of that search tree, evaluating each assertion in turn, and succeeding when a leaf node is hit. Upon backtracking, the tree traversal continues from where it left off, looking for alternative solutions, and ultimately failing when the search tree is exhausted and no more solutions are to be found.